# Oracle Apex Form Process returning Virtual Column not allowed

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a Form page (created using the form with report option), that uses table real/actual columns (not a view). But when updating I'm getting the following error:

ORA-01733: virtual column not allowed here

All columns selected on the Form region are existing (not a single case statement for example, nor joins).
Query is literally this:

```
select
column1,
column2,
...
from my_table
```

Haven't been able to reproduce the error, doesn't occur with other tables (and the one I have with the error has confidential data).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You said that you have a **form** page. Where does "query is literally this" come from? There's no *query* on a form page; it belongs to report. Did you run page in **debug mode** and check debug info?

Comment: I figured it out thanks to that piece of text, so I had an upper(column) as ... which I guess counted as a virtual one. Thanks littlefoot

Comment: Don't forget you can answer your own question, and then accept the answer.  This is an interesting error that I'm sure others may face sometime!